# Facebook graph API version retrieving

Tags: facebook-graph-api, version, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to retrieve the number of the Facebook Graph API latest version programmatically?

Comment: Why you need to find Graph API latest version programmatically?

Comment: I'd like to notify customer automatically that FB API code requires attention and (possibly) some changes. Having this note in-time will reduce amount of (possibly) caught failures by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actual answer but it may be helpful. I am not sure is it possible or not to get latest API version using API call but we can get notified via email when API will be changed. https://www.apichangelog.com provide this kind of service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to get info about current version of facebook graph and also the previous versions.
https://github.com/thunderluca/GraphVersionHelper